# Distribution of sine of uniform random variable on $[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable having uniform distribution on $[0, 2\pi]$. What distribution has the random variable $Y=\sin X$ ? I think, it is also uniform. Am I right?

Comment: No, it is not. Loosely speking: Since the sine is "slow" near its extremes, if is more likely that $Y\approx 1$ than that $Y\approx 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118108/321264

Answer (score 12):

By the Jacobian formula, $$f_Y(y)=\frac{\mathbf 1_{|y|\lt1}}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}.$$
This is the so-called [Arcsine distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution), which famously appears in [probability theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_laws_(Wiener_process)) and in [number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_arcsine_law), as shown by [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s) mathematical [giants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_L%C3%A9vy_(mathematician)) from the 20th century:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
[image]

Answer (score 9):

The support of the distribution is of course $[-1,1]$.  For $y\in[0,1]$, we have
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y\le y) & = \Pr(0\le X\le\arcsin y\text{ or }2\pi\ge X\ge \pi-\arcsin y) \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\arcsin y + (2\pi-(\pi-\arcsin y))}{2\pi}.
\end{align}
The density is the derivative of that, and that is not a constant function, so it's not uniformly distributed.

Comment: It is a pity to avoid giving the density, is it not?

Comment: OK, here it is: $\dfrac1{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}$. ${}\qquad{}$